# Java - search the maximum id in the table on database

Tags: java, database

I have method which one search largest id in database and return that id + 1

```
static int searchIdNewPlane(Connection con) {
    int maxId = 1;
    try {


        String query = "SELECT id FROM Plane ORDER BY id DESC Limit 1 ";

        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            maxId = rs.getInt("id");

        }

        return maxId + 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 1;    //error
    }
}
```

Is this a good idea for the solution of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your database to do that for you.

`SELECT MAX(id) as maxid FROM Plane`

```
while( rs.next() )
{
    maxId = rs.getInt('maxid');
}
return maxId + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a mySQL or Oracle database, you can use

`SELECT MAX(id) FROM Plane`

This will return the (single) highest ID without the need to limit your query.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the database, much better solution would be to use sequences. This approach has some inherent problems (not thread-safe, ...).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you want to take a new ID to INSERT a new record.
Several database vendors have their own mechanism to insert new records with a generated new primary key. Which is safer / more efficient. Think of:

```
- A: get new MAX + 1 = 100
- B: get new MAX + 1 = 100
- B: insert with ID = 100
- A: failed insert with ID = 100
```

JDBC has implemented a vendor independent way to do an insert without primary key, and retrieve afterwards the generated key. (Even for inserting several records, and having more than one generated key per record - if supported.)

Say in MySQL you have a primary key ID, INT with AUTOINCREMENT.

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into TB_classes"
    + "(CLASS_TEACHER_ID , CLASS_NAME , CLASS_YEAR ,  CLASS_SUBJECT) "
    + "values (? , ? , ? ,?)")) {

    ps.setString(1, request.getParameter("teacher"));
    ps.setString(2, request.getParameter("name1"));
    ps.setString(3, request.getParameter("year"));
    ps.setString(4, request.getParameter("subject"));

    int updateCount = ps.executeUpdate(); // 1 expected on insert.

    try (ResultSet primaryKeysRS = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        if (primaryKeyRS.next()) {
            int id = primaryKeyRS.getInt(1);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

(Here try-with-resources closes things automatically.)

All this has the advantage, that doing this task twice at the same time will not mix up the ID, giving twice the same, or such. Also it is more efficient to leave it to the database.

Comment: I know but I need that method :D